# Remove the [playstation-4] and [playstation] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It seems obvious to me that these tags aren't needed. The [question they are used in](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/123/155) only tags them because the real hardware in question is a hard drive that will be used with a PS4.

Comment: Fair warning before I ask this question: I don't have a PS4. Does a PS4 have special requirements for the types of drives you can install or would any standard drive work as a replacement? If there is something special required, I think at least one of the tags is important. If not, and it's really just asking for a standard drive, I am in agreement with you

Comment: @Andy That's true. I can understand this if there is PS4-specific hardware involved, but it didn't seem like that was the case.

Comment: @Andy I am not sure about the PS4, but the PS3's hdd slot is a standard size. I bought a 1TB drive a few years ago that was taller and it didn't fit. If this site had existed then, it would have saved me some hassle.

Comment: @Adam Are you asking to permanently remove that tags, or just for this question?

Comment: I want them permanently removed. I could just go edit them out if I was concerned about the question tags.

Comment: @Adam Tags are automatically removed when they aren't in use on any question. There's a lag of a few hours because it isn't done instantly, there's a daily script that removes them in batches. So to get rid of a tag, edit the questions that have it. (Stack Exchange staff can purge a tag by accessing the database directly, but they'd only do that if there were hundreds of questions or more.)

Comment: @Gilles Ah, thanks. I wasn't aware of that feature as I haven't ran into this problem before. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the PlayStation-4 tag should be allowed here (not sure how I feel about the PlayStation tag yet). Console tags give us context as to what the hardware is for, just like the laptop tag. I can see questions asking about other hardware that interacts with gaming consoles, i.e. what wireless keyboards work with my PS4 and Xbox One? This is of course assuming that gaming consoles are on-topic here.

Comment: I agree, but the tag is only needed if it's necessary for recommending hardware. If someone's looking for an external drive to connect with their PS4, it's not needed; if they're requiring a PS4-specific connection or interface, it is needed.